# Does variable X, for example, X= average daily activity of a person, change with age?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, sample-size

I would like to answer the following question: Does variable X (numerical variable), for example, X= average daily activity of a person, change with age? For example, can I say that generally older people tend to have less daily activity than younger people?

I have 3 groups of people, grouped by age, each person with one value of average daily activity. For example:

G1 - N=10 all 50 years old, each person with a value for variable X

G2 - N=2 all 5 years old, each person with a value for variable X

G3 - N=40 all 20 years old, each person with a value for variable X

I already tried to plot all points (disregarding groups) in a 2D plot Age vs Variable X, and calculate Pearson and Spearman correlations to try to detect a correlation between the variables. Is this valid?

Should I keep the groups and try to perform a hypothesis test to check for differences between groups? How can I deal with different sample sizes?

What would you do to try to understand if there is some relation between age and variable X?

Thank you!

Comment: Be careful about how you formulate your question.  Your data will not permit you to determine whether a quantity *changes* with age.  All you can do is compare that quantity among age groups.  It is possible, for instance, for all the older people to have lower daily activity values than younger people, yet for each older individual to have *greater* daily activity than they did in their youth.

Comment: A priori, the answer is obviously "yes." The real question is  "how does it change," not "does it change." I would suggest using pairwise confidence intervals for the mean differences.